# How to define a module being required, but not a dependency in Apache Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a Maven multi-module project, with one (or many) modules called "plugin-xx", in the main "runtime" module, I'm dynamically loading a class from a plugin module.
To avoid classloading conflicts, I'm creating a new classloader, pointing to the jar in the target directory of "plugin-xx".

So for the "runtime" module, I would like to tell Maven, that "plugin-xx" needs to produce a jar, but I don't want this jar to be in the classpath of "runtime".

Adding "plugin-xx" as a dependency would include it into the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `plugin-xx` as a dependency but use a dependency scope other than `compile`. I think you want this one:

- `<scope>provided</scope>`

From the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

I'm not totally clear on your requirements so it's *possible* that you want this instead:

- `<scope>runtime</scope>`

From the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> **runtime**
>
> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runtime` scope for your dependency. Definition looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>plugin-xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin-xx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

You won't see the plugin on classpath in your main module during compilation time but it will be placed on classpath on runtime so you can dynamically load it with your ClassLoader.